# Request address from google maps(using api URL)

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, street-address

Is there anyway to request address from google maps using latitude and longitude?
I am using iOS SDK so I want URL to make the request with ASIHTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the **reverse geocoding API** provided by google maps.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

If you are going to use this on a map somewhere, you should also make sure you refer to the google terms of service.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html

EDIT
Mapkit provides a reverse geocoder delegate for you to use, but it has to be used in conjuction with MkMapView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008324